# How to replicate TeXify / Yap current page display behavior with PDFTeXify / Adobe Reader?

Tags: pdftex, miktex

After TeXify finishes, Yap displays the same page it was on prior to the TeXify.

How do I replicate this behavior with PDFTeXify / Adobe Reader so that it displays the same page I was on prior to the recompile?

Presently, Reader displays the first page by default after PDFTeXify creates the pdf file.

Thanks.

Current setup:  MikTex 2.9, WinEdt 7.0, Adobe Reader X and Yap 2.9.

Comment: If Adobe Reader is not an absolute requirement I would try Sumatra PDF. It works the way you want it without any further hassles. Otherwise DDE commands to Adobe Reader are most likely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You didn’t say, which TeX editor you use. So, I can only give you some hints.

- For the call of `pdflatex` you need to add the command line switch `--pdf` to `texify`.
- With Adobe Reader you every time must close the generated PDF file by hand before recompiling, or your TeX editor must be able to use DDE. As Alexander in the comments already wrote, [Sumatra PDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/) is an excellent replacement for most needs.
- You must change some settings in your TeX editor. The behaviour, that it starts in pdf mode only on page 1, is unknown here with TeXnicCenter and different PDF readers, but … see my first sentence.